# I am making a rubber band gun but i cant seem to get the button to work with my code to turn the servo?

Tags: arduino-ide

```
#include <Servo.h>
const int buttonPin = 3;
int buttonState = 0;

Servo myservo;   
void setup() {
    myservo.attach(2);    
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);   
    if (buttonState == HIGH){ myservo.write(90); }   
    else { myservo.write(155); }   
    delay(1000); 
}
```

Comment: And what exactly does not work? What do you see happending or not happending? What have you expected?

Comment: So it is supposed to move a servo when I push a button but the Servo just moves back and forth randomly.

Comment: Floating input. Show your wiring.

Comment: You may also print buttonState and check it's value in the serial monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your button between pin3 and GND, and use the internal pullup resistor like this:

```
#include <Servo.h>
const int buttonPin = 3;
int buttonState = 0;

Servo myservo;   
void setup()
{
    myservo.attach(2);    
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop()
{
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    if(buttonState == LOW)
    {
      myservo.write(90);
    }
    else
    {
      myservo.write(155);
    }   
    delay(1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems you should pay attention to when using the button:

- Floating input: => using pull-up or pull-down resistor, [see Using pull-up/ pull-down](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-button)
- Chattering phenomenon => Debounce [See button debounce](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-button-debounce)

Comment: Since the servo pulse frequency is about 50 Hz it has a clock period of about 20 ms. This is more than enough to debounce buttons, so there is no need for it.